# how to pass images to UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have url .Now  I can get images for Url.But now i need that 8 images pass to ScrollView.So Please give me any idea about my problem.
I tried like this:-

```
NSMutableArray *al=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:nil];
    for (NSDictionary *diction in al)
    {


        NSString *geting =[diction valueForKey:@"dealimage"];
        NSLog(@"dealimage is %@",geting);

        NSData *getdata=[[NSData alloc]initWithData:[NSData dataFromBase64String:geting]];
        NSLog(@"good day %@",getdata);
        dataimages=[UIImage imageWithData:getdata];
        NSLog(@"dataimages %@",dataimages);

        [imagesarray addObject:dataimages];


    }
```

When i Print imagesarray it's showing

```
images array is array(
    "<UIImage: 0x7539b70>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7176e00>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7182960>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7185d40>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7541d00>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7186e30>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7186ff0>",
    "<UIImage: 0x7187410>"
)
```

example:-
[image]
Please tell me how to add Scroll on my getting images.
Thanks in Advanced.

Comment: Use a collection view.

Comment: @duci9y thanks but i need scroll on images so Please give me any idea about how to scroll image CollectionView .when i pass images on CollectionView Cell jest displaying only

Comment: A collection view is a scroll view. It scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add each of these images as a subview of a UIScrollView and set the content size of the scroll view to be the total width of the images combined. This is how you do it for a single image.

```
UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imagesarray[0]];
[scrollview addSubview:image];
scollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(image.frame.size.height, image.frame.size.width);
```

Hope that gives you a good starting point.

Comment: i tried as you said gettingScrollView =[[UIScrollView alloc]init];
    UIImageView *imagescroll = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:imagesarray[0]];
    [gettingScrollView addSubview:imagescroll];
    gettingScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(100, 75);
      [self.view addSubview:gettingScrollView];
    gettingScrollView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 80);
     imagesarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    gettingScrollView.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];  but i am not getting images Please help me

Comment: Is there any reason why you are reinitialising the imagesarray after you have added the image at index 0 to the scroll view?

Comment: k where i did reinitialising Please tell me

Comment: You have in you comment imagesarray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init] after you have added images pertaining to be in that array to the scroll view. I am not sure whether this is your issue but I don't know why you are doing this.